# How to prepopulate country in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

I need to prepopulate country name of the user in jsp.

So far I have this:

```
    <input type="text" name="foreigncountry" id="foreigncountry" class="nice input-text" size="20" maxlength="20"
    <% 
        String country = userInfo.getAddressInfo().getCountry();
        if (country.equalsIgnoreCase("CA")) {                                                   
            out.print("value='Canada'");
        else if((country.equalsIgnoreCase("KZ"))){
            out.print("value='Kazakhstan'");
    } %>
>
```

the problem is I have about 180 countries and I don't think it is good to have so many "if else" statements in my code.

Usually I would use drop down list to choose country like this:

```
<select id="countries" name="countries">
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL" selected>Albania</option>
    ...
</select>
```

But I dont know how to bind them to make it work.

Bottom line I would prefer to have drop down list with country names and prepopulate country from the value I get from scriptlet.

Any advice is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally I solved it. Not sure if its best solution so if you know better way then pls let me know.

Step1: make input type as hidden and get value from jsp

```
<input type="hidden" name="foreigncountry" id="foreigncountry" class="nice input-text" size="20" maxlength="20"
<% 
    String country = userInfo.getAddressInfo().getCountry();
    if (country != null && country.trim().length()>0 && !("US").equalsIgnoreCase(country)) {                            
        out.print("value='" + country.trim() + "'");
    } else {
        out.print("value=''");
    }
%>
```

Step2: Use jQuery to prepopulate country

```
<select id="countries" name="countries">
    <option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>
    <option value="AL">Albania</option>
    ...
</select>
```

And

```
<script>
    var val = document.getElementById("foreigncountry").value;
    $('#countries').val(val);
</script>
```